# How can I make my finished program read a file, via terminal input?

Tags: c++, terminal, command

this is silly but I have completed a program that takes in a file to use.. But the problem is I don't know how to point to it in the terminal? Im on a macbook pro, and right now to run my C++ programs I type in

"g++ FillMe.cpp -o main; ./main"

BUT now how do I make my FillMe program actually read a file? How can I point to it in the terminal command? Thanks.

The code that works is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Text {



string text;

public:

Text() {}

Text(const string& fname) {

    ifstream ifs(fname.c_str());

    string line;

    while (getline(ifs, line))

        text += line + '\n';

    }

    string contents() {

        return text;

    }

};

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

        if (argc > 1)

        {

            Text t1;

            Text t2(argv[1]);

            cout << "t1 :\n" << t1.contents() << endl;

            cout << "t2 :\n" << t2.contents() << endl;

        }

    }
```

"

Comment: Use the shell's input redirection features :P ...

Comment: AHH IT WORKS!! THANX BUT how does ./main know which cpp file to use to work the myinput.txt file? I have like 4 different cpp files on my desktop but somehow it chooses the right one. And we dont specify in the terminal which cpp file to use.... sooooo

Comment: NVM>. first I compile my main file.. then I use that compiled main to use the text file... Now it makes sense..

Comment: Let your program either read more command line arguments for multiple input files (`argv[2]`, `argv[3]`, etc.), or just take the standard input stream and say `cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt | ./main`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $ g++ FillMe.cpp -o main 
 $ ./main
```

> How can I point to it in the terminal command?

There are several options you can take.

For your actual setting you want to see filenames from the programs command line arguments. So for multiple file arguments you need to access these in a loop

```
    if (argc > 1) {
        for(int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
            Text txt(argv[i]);
            cout << "txt:\n" << txt.contents() << endl;
    }
```

and call from the command line

```
$ ./main file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

---

The IMHO better and more flexible solution is to let your program read from standard input by default. Thus you can simply make use of the shell's input redirection features, like e.g. a pipe

```
$ cat file1.txt file2.txt file2.txt | ./main
```

to feed `./main`'s `std::cin` input stream.

Alternatively

```
$ ./main < myinputfile.txt
```

or one of the many other options as [documented here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

But the latter depends on your use case. If you need to process input from known separate files, you're better off passing the names as program parameters using `argv`.

Comment: Im trying to do this but I can't get it to work, I keep typing into terminal:

cat Text.cpp Hello.txt | ./main

And it still doesn't work

Comment: @2WeeksToGO I have edited and reopened it. Hope it's more helpful now.

Answer (score -1):

the ./main executable knows which cpp file to use because of this line in your program

```
Text t2(argv[1]);
```

So when you type

```
$ ./main input.txt
```

This line use argument 1 from the command line `'input.txt'` to construct a new Text object.

The construction is taken care of by this line:

```
  Text(const string& fname)
```

Here you are passing a string name to the Text class and then using that filename to open file handle

Comment: _'the ./main executable knows which `.cpp` file to use because of this line in your program ...'_ I don't get it. Can you elaborate on this please? The _'which `.cpp` file to use'_ part in particular.